# monit : reboot server on failed health check

Tags: monit

I am trying to get monit to reboot a server if something catastrophic happens, this is to deal with some very experimental stuff we are doing with docker. Ideally I would be able to do

```
then exec "reboot now"
```

or

```
then exec "/var/reboot_now_script"
```

but they fail to work. Is it possible to restart the server with monit?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we use this format and it works for us:

```
then exec "/sbin/shutdown -r now"
```